# How can i use array_push by a php extension pdo?

Tags: php, pdo

I want to know how to push an fetched array by using pdo.how can we do that?I know it might be possible so, I need help guys.

```
         $done = false;
         $name = $_SESSION['people'] ['name'];
         $result = array(); 
         $query = 'SELECT * FROM people WHERE name = :me';
              $query_paramt = array( 
                 ':me' => $name
                );

                try 
                  { 
                    // Execute the query to create the user 
                        $stmts = $db->prepare($query); 
                        $results = $stmts->execute($query_paramt); 
                        if($results == true)
                          {
                              $done = true;
                          }
                  }   
                catch(PDOException $ex) 
                        { 
                            // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
                            // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
                            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
                        }

                   $row = $stmts ->fetchAll();
```

Actually I want to use array_push on that fetched data and keep all in `$result` array after that I was planning to encode that on json format like :-

```
  echo json_encode(array("result" => $result));
```

Comment: Did you search such information or just read the docs?

Comment: @VladimirSerykh I am working with pdo for my site and I have a situation where I need to use array_push so, I was hoping for some answer if its possible or not?

Answer (score 2):

Doing something like this would add foo to the returned array from PDO.

```
$arr = $pdo->fetchAll();
array_push($arr,"foo");
```